# Send HTML formatted email using Gmail API and Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, email, gmail-api

The following javascript code successfully sends an email message via the Gmail API. However the table formatting, specifically the table and column (cell) width settings, seem to be ignored.

```
function sendMail(email) {
    var to = email;
    var subject = "HTML formatted email";
    var content = "";
    content += "<html><body>";
    content += "<table width='100%'><tr><td>"; // Outer table
    content += "<table width='60%'>"; // Nested table
    content += "<tr><td width='70%'>This is a row</td><td width='30%'>999999</td></tr>";
    content += "<tr><td width='70%'>So is this</td><td width='30%'>9999</td></tr>";
    content += "</table>";
    content += "</td></tr></table>";
    content += "</body></html>";
    var email =
            "From: 'me'\r\n" +
            "To: " + to + "\r\n" +
            "Subject: " + subject + "\r\n" +
            "Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8\r\n" +
            "Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable\r\n\r\n" +
            content;
    var base64EncodedEmail = window.btoa(email).replace(/\+/g, "-").replace(/\//g, "_");
    var request = gapi.client.gmail.users.messages.send({
        "userId": "me",
        "resource": {
            "raw": base64EncodedEmail
        }
    });
    request.execute();
}
```

The email message looks as follows:

```
This is a row 999999
So is this    9999
```

Everything I've researched on sending HTML formatted email messages says to use nested tables and inline styling. Why is my width styling not working?

Comment: Try removing the `%` sign. `width='400'` should do the trick.

Answer (score 11):

After much searching, experimentation and testing I finally figured out that I needed to set the content-transfer-encoding value to base64:

```
var email =
        "From: 'me'\r\n" +
        "To: " + to + "\r\n" +
        "Subject: " + subject + "\r\n" +
        "Content-Type: text/html; charset='UTF-8'\r\n" +
        "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n\r\n" +
        "<html><body>" +
        content +
        "</body></html>";
```

Hope this saves others with similar question some time.

Comment: content-transfer-encoding change worked for me..and saved my day

Comment: wow, my  hero, saved me lots, did u also try adding attachments? that's my next blocker